# Xamarin - iOS Multiple polygons on map

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am currently following [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/polygon-map-overlay/) tutorial for adding a polygon to a map. I need to be able to add multiple polygons to my map, so I have slightly altered the code so that I can use `addOverlays` which takes in an array of `IMKOverlay` objects instead of one `addOverlay` which just takes in a single `IMKOverlay` object.

This doesn't work however... It only draws the first polygon on the map!

```
void addPolygonsToMap()
        {
            overlayList = new List<IMKOverlay>();
            for (int i = 0; i < polygons.Count; i++)
            {

                    CLLocationCoordinate2D[] coords = new CLLocationCoordinate2D[polygons[i].Count];

                    int index=0;
                    foreach (var position in polygons[i])
                    {
                        coords[index] = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
                        index++;
                    }
                    var blockOverlay = MKPolygon.FromCoordinates(coords);
                    overlayList.Add(blockOverlay);

            }
            IMKOverlay[] imko = overlayList.ToArray();
            nativeMap.AddOverlays(imko);

        }
```

In [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/12585/adding-multiple-overlays-to-a-map-view) discussion, it would appear that I have to call a new instance of `MKPolygonRenderer` each time I need to add another polygon to my map, but I'm unsure how this example translates to my code. Here is my `MKPolygonRenderer` function:

```
MKOverlayRenderer GetOverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlayWrapper)
  {
      if (polygonRenderer == null && !Equals(overlayWrapper, null)) {
          var overlay = Runtime.GetNSObject(overlayWrapper.Handle) as IMKOverlay;
          polygonRenderer = new MKPolygonRenderer(overlay as MKPolygon) {
              FillColor = UIColor.Red,
              StrokeColor = UIColor.Blue,
              Alpha = 0.4f,
              LineWidth = 9
          };
      }
      return polygonRenderer;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new renderer instance each time `OverlayRenderer` is called, there is no need to cache the renderer in a class level variable as the `MKMapView` will cache the renderers as needed.

#### Subclass `MKMapViewDelegate`:

```
class MyMapDelegate : MKMapViewDelegate
{
    public override MKOverlayRenderer OverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
    {
        switch (overlay)
        {
            case MKPolygon polygon:
                var prenderer = new MKPolygonRenderer(polygon)
                {
                    FillColor = UIColor.Red,
                    StrokeColor = UIColor.Blue,
                    Alpha = 0.4f,
                    LineWidth = 9
                };
                return prenderer;
            default:
                throw new Exception($"Not supported: {overlay.GetType()}");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Instance and assign the delegate to your map:

```
mapDelegate = new MyMapDelegate();
map.Delegate = mapDelegate;
```

Note: Store the instance of your `MyMapDelegate` in a class level variable as you do not want to get GC'd

#### Update:

`MKMapView` has two steps involved to display an overlay on its map.

```
1. Calling `AddOverlay` and `AddOverlays`
```

First you add overlays to the map that conform to `IMKOverlay`. There are basic built-in types such as `MKCircle`, `MKPolygon`, etc... but you can also design your own overlays; i.e. overlays that define the location of severe weather (lightning, storm clouds, tornados, etc..). These MKOverlays describe the geo-location of the item **but not** how to draw it.

```
2. Responding to `OverlayRenderer` requests
```

When the display area of the map intersects with one of the overlays, the map need to draw it on the screen. The map's delegate (your `MKMapViewDelegate` subclass) is called to supply a `MKOverlayRenderer` that defines the drawing routines to paint the overlay on the map.

This drawing involves converting the geo-coordinates of the overlay to local display coordinates (helper methods are available) using Core Graphics routines (UIKit can be used with some limitations). There are basic built-in renderers for MKCircleRenderer, MKPolygonRenderer, etc.. that can be used or you can write your own `MKOverlayRenderer` subclass.

You could supply a custom way to renderer a `MKCircle` overlay, maybe a target-style red/white multi-ringed bullseye, instead of the way the default circle renderer draws it, or custom renderers that draw severe storm symbols within the bounds of a `MKPolygon` to match your custom severe storm overlays.

My Example code:

Since you are using `MKPolygon` to build your overlays, you can use the `MKPolygonRenderer` to display them. In my example, I provide a pattern matching switch (C# 6) that returns a semi-transparent  Red/Blue MKPolygonRenderer for *every* MKPolygon that you added to the map (if you added a non-MKPolygon based overlay it will throw an exception).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm just not sure how I should be calling it for each of my polygons. Currently they are stored as a `List<List<Position>> Polygons`

Comment: You do not call it the map does, it exists as a method within a `MKMapViewDelegate` subclass that is assigned to  `MKMapView.MapDelegate`... Do you have a MKMapViewDelegate subclass?

Comment: No I don't have a MKMapViewDelegate subclass :s

Comment: @BarneyChambers I updated my answer, see if that helps

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it now

Comment: I don't think I understand

Comment: What do you not understand 

Comment: I'm struggling to understand on a high level how to piece the puzzle together with your code example

Comment: @BarneyChambers See if my update helps your puzzle  

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck in this issue and I have found the way to create the sub class of MKPolygon.

I have checked it with my example and it works like a charm. But not sure that Apple may reject my app or not.

```
public class CvPolyon : MKPolygon
    {
        public CustomObject BoundaryOption { get; }

        public CvPolyon1(MKPolygon polygon, CustomObject  boundaryOption)
            :base(polygon.Handle)
        {
            BoundaryOption = boundaryOption;
        }
    }
```

We can add polygon on map like this.

```
var polygon = MKPolygon.FromCoordinates(coordinates);
                    var overlay = new CvPolyon(polygon, new CustomObject());
                    mapView.AddOverlay(overlay);
```

We can recognize our polygon in the class which extends MKMapViewDelegate like this.

```
public override MKOverlayRenderer OverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlay)
        {
            if (overlay is CvPolyon polygon)
            {
                var polygonRenderer = new MKPolygonRenderer(polygon)
                {
                    FillColor   = polygon.BoundaryOption.AreaColor,
                    StrokeColor = polygon.BoundaryOption.LineColor,
                    Alpha       = polygon.BoundaryOption.Alpha,
                    LineWidth   = polygon.BoundaryOption.LineWidth
                };

                if (polygon.BoundaryOption.IsDashedLine)
                    polygonRenderer.LineDashPattern = new[] { new NSNumber(2), new NSNumber(5) };

                return polygonRenderer;
            }

            return mapView.RendererForOverlay(overlay);
        }
```